# Swapping image src to a very large base64 encoded image causes whole window to freeze for a second or 2 (electron)

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have an app where I am trying to stream images from a python app to the electron app. The streaming of the data is working now but every time I switch the image src to the new one that comes in, the whole window lags for a second or two before the image is updated. By lag I mean it freezes and is non-interactable.
The code when I change the image src loks like this:

```
static changeImageDisplay(imageData) {
        if (!Camera.imageZoomHandler) {
            let image = new Image();
            image.id = "fodImageMainWindow";
            Camera.currentImageSrc = "data:image/png;base64," + imageData.toString("base64");
            image.src = Camera.currentImageSrc;
            document.getElementById("fodImgContainer").appendChild(image);
            image.addEventListener("dblclick", () => {
                openCameraWindow(imageData);
            });
            Camera.imageZoomHandler = wheelzoom(image, {zoom: 0.2});
        } else {
            Camera.currentImageSrc = "data:image/png;base64," + imageData.toString("base64");
            Camera.imageZoomHandler.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + Camera.currentImageSrc + ")";
        }
        // sendImageToWindow(imageData);
    }
```

To be clear the lag is 100% happeneing on this line : `image.src = Camera.currentImageSrc;`
and this line: `Camera.imageZoomHandler.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + Camera.currentImageSrc + ")";` . Also the image size that is coming in ~14mb

Comment: big question is, which process are you using for this code? You should NOT have it in the main process. Everything you put in main process will block the main thread completely. That is why you want to have it in a renderer process, potentially even a dedicated hidden worker window for heavy lifting.

Comment: This is in a renderer for the mainwindow. This is not in Main.js

Comment: Loading 14MB of text into the UI is never a good idea. If possible, do it with a normal link to the image (even if it's just a local `file:///` URI)

Comment: Thanks @Sv443! saving the image to a file and then using that as src made it way faster and more responsive!